# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PostForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class createPost(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'forum/createPost.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback and your URL pattern.

Comment: Please format your post correctly.

Comment: Where do you call it? and How?